# What is the best design approach for attributes that are not directly related to an entity?

Tags: java, oop, architecture, composition

I want to create a mini-application in Java which simulates a library. I created a class called `Book` which the following attributes:

```
public class Book {
    private final String ISBN;
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String domain;
    private int numberOfPages;
}
```

I want to add two more attributes: *stock* and *price*. But these attributes are not directly related to a real book (like *ISBN* or *title*) so I don't know exactly where to add them: in `Book` or in another class...

One idea would be to create a new class called `BookView` (not sure if it's the best name) and to add the attributes like this:

```
public class BookView {
    private Book book;
    private short stock;
    private float price;
}
```

Another idea would be to extend the `Book` and create a `BookWithDetails` child class which adds the stock and the price, but I'm not sure the inheritance comes in handy for this scenario:

```
public BookWithDetails extends Book {
    private short stock;
    private float price;
}
```

What is the best approach for situations like these?

Comment: The stock would represent how many books of that kind are in the repository. **Example**: 10 books of *Thinking in Java, 4th Edition*

Comment: So the managing class would be just for a certain type of book, right? All books would be of the same title?

Comment: Yes, you got that right. The stock and the price describe one particular book. 10 *Thinking in Java* at $50 each, for instance.

Comment: Is the book manager class responsible for initializing the book information, i.e., creating books in the manager class?

Comment: I think I will use a `BookRepository` class which would be a mini-database. And that part will be responsible to add new books and retrieve them as needed. And `BookStock` will keep the book info, as *Bohemian* suggested.

Comment: Your BookView, perhaps better named BookStock, is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario, it seems like creating a class similar to `BookView`, as shown in your post, would be the best option:

```
public class BookManager {
    private short stock;
    private float price;
    private Book book;
}
```

This way, the manager class keeps the extra information about the price and quantity of the book separated from the actual book itself.

Because the fields are declared as `private`, you should add setter and getter methods to retrieve the values of the fields. As an example of some getter methods:

```
public short getStock() {
    return stock;
}

public float getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public Book getBook() {
    return book;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The additional attributes do not belong on the `Book` for two reasons:

- **They describe something else** - rather than describing the book, they describe *lots* of books available at a specific price, and
- **One book may have multiple such attributes** - in theory, you may have five books available for $10 each, and and three books available for $8 each.

Hence your `BookView` class is a good choice to represent a book lot, except I would rename it:

```
public class BookLot {
    private Book book;
    private short stock;
    private float price;
}
```

Also consider changing the `price` to `int`, with the understanding that it represents cents or whatever it is in the desired currency. This is because `float` and `double` are not very good at representing decimal fractions, and `BigDecimal` is likely going to be too wasteful for representing tiny decimal numbers.

Comment: piggy packing off of this answer.  If you need an accurate price, look into Java's `Currency` Object

Comment: Why would `BigDecimal` be "too wasteful"? Using an `int` instead sounds like a micro-optimization. `BigDecimal` would make it easy to stick with readable dollar/cent amounts while having calculations always return correct results.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Well, OP seems to be very conscious about the size of his objects - he's using `short` and `float` in place of `int` and `double`, so I figured he's not going to like `BigDecimal` very much. It's only a suggestion, really, the actual answer pretty much ends after the two bullet points at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the answer was in your question : *What is the best design approach for attributes **that are not directly related to** an entity?*

If you need to *extend* an object with features not related to the object, think composition. If the extended object *is* a previous one, think inheritance.

And correct, the name isn't the best, lets say it's a `BookProduct` or `BookCommodity` (don't really like this one…)

```
public class BookProduct {
    private Book book;
    private short stock;
    private float price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to have an alternate view to the others here: I think you should have both `stock` and `price` in the `Book` class. Let me elaborate:

**What is real? How do you define "real"?**

Sometimes people say, that in OO we model the "real world". That is not entirely true. We model the business, and we call everything "real" that exists in the business domain. Not all of these things *are* actually real in the conventional sense, and most professions (i.e. "businesses") have special terminology which might assign different semantics to words from their "conventional" day-to-day meanings.

**What is a "Book"?**

I'm not a native English speaker, but the word "Book" has multiple meanings I believe. The word "Book" might refer to a whole group of physical objects, or to a single, concrete physical object.

For example: Author X has a new Book. Or: Can I borrow *that* Book?

**Library**

Things get even more complicated, since your Domain is a "Library". Just talk to a librarian (i.e. a "business" person in your Domain).

Will the librarian say: "My current stock of BookView is ..."? She will probably not say that, she will say: "My current stock of Book X is ...". Or something along the lines.

Also, how will she call the single physical object that you can check out? Most probably she will say: "Here is your *copy* of Book X." Or something similar.

**Modeling**

Now, that we know what "things" exist in our Domain, let's look at how we model that. In OO we don't care about the data that much, so it's not actually that important *where* these data reside.

The important part is the *behavior*, what these "things" can provide for us. My first try would look like this:

```java
public interface Book {
    Copy checkout();
}

public interface Copy {
    void return(); // I know, keyword
}
```

Probably I would need the `stock` and the `price` in the `Book` to facilitate `checkout()`, but this is secondary based on the *behavior* I assigned to the `Book`. Without *behavior*, the data is irrelevant.